# passing route parameter to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Right now I have existing productsController which delivers products data using dataService

```
myApp.controller("productsController", function ($scope, $http, dataService) {
    $scope.productsData = dataService;    

    dataService.getProducts()
    .then(function () {
        //success

    },
    function () {
        // error
        alert("could not load products");
    });
});
```

this works fine, products are rendered on my view properly.
Now I want to open product details on product click
so I add

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in productsData.products">
    <td>{{ product.Name }}</td>           
    <td>
        <a ng-href="{{ product.Id }}">
            <img ng-src="{{ product.thumbnail }}" width="50" height="50" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I added corresponding route

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    ...
    .when("/product/:id", {
        controller: "productsController",
        templateUrl: "/templates/productDetailsView.html"
    })
    ...
}
```

my question is:
**How can I pass this id parameter to productsController** *so I can pass it further to my data service*
which will return data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inject [`$routeParams`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) into your controller.

```
myApp.controller("productsController", ['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams.id);         
}]);
```